# How to keep the font remain constant for our Application irrespective of the font changes in device in Android

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application in which I was using some default font. When I install the app in device and if the device changed the font in its settings to italic, then the font in my application is also changed. I want the font to  remain constant in my application irrespective of  font changes in device. 
can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: But in my App , I am creating EditText dynamically. I have so many EditText fields. Then for all the fields we need to do like this or is there any other method?

Answer (score 1):

Resembling problem I have resolved in following way: created own TextView/EditText widgets extending standard ones, like:

```
public class SimpleTextView extends TextView 
{
    public final static int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE=14;

    public SimpleTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    }

    public SimpleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    }

    public SimpleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Later you can use them in layout xml's like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
        <{my-package}.SimpleTextView
                android:text="Blah-blah"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But in my App , I am  creating EditText dynamically. I have so many EditText fields. Then for all the fields we need to do like this or is there any other method?